# How do I make a field have a prefixed value and an X to remove the value

Tags: javascript, forms

I want my form to have a field with a pre-fixed value like this:

New York **x**

And let the user be able to change it by clicking on the X. In other words they click the **X** and they get a text field to write whatever they want.

Is there an easy way to do this or is it a lot of code?

--

Box9: After integrating your code it doesn't input the prefilled value when submitted:

```
<form class="questionform" name="questionform-0" id="questionform-0">

<textarea class="question-box" cols="12" rows="5"  id="question-box-' . $questionformid . '" name="title"  type="text" maxlength="200" size="28"></textarea>

<span class="prefilled"><script language="javascript"> document.write('' + geoip_city() +''); </script><a href="#"> X</a></span>

<input type="text" name="question" style="display:none">

<input  type="button" name="ask" value="Publicar" onclick="askquestion('questionform-0'); window.location.reload(true);">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".prefilled a").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".prefilled").hide().next().show().focus();
    return false; // Prevent page from jumping to the top
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is more of a javascript question. not php related. i have retagged appropriately.

Comment: This form mechanism called a "hint" in most frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic solution, as long as the markup is as below:

HTML:

```
<span class="prefilled">New York <a href="#">X</a></span>
<input type="text" name="city" style="display:none" value="New York">
```

Javascript:

```
$(".prefilled a").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".prefilled").hide().next().val("").show().focus();
    return false; // Prevent page from jumping to the top
});
```

---

Seeing that you're getting the value of "New York" from script and not in the HTML, you might want to set the value of the input like this:

```
$("input[name=question]").val(geoip_city());
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't submit the prefilled value when I submit the form. It does however submit it if I change it. What do I need to change? I updated the question to show the form with your code integrated

Comment: @Liso22, My fault, I overlooked that. All you need to do is set the value of the `<input>` in the HTML to be "New York" as well. Then set that to "" when the `<a>` is clicked. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Could you tell me how to add <script language="javascript"> document.write('' + geoip_city() +''); </script> to the field's value and onfocus?

<input type="text" name="question" value="" style="display:none" onfocus="if (this.value == '') {this.value=''}">

Comment: @Liso22 Ignore the `value` and the `onfocus` attributes in the HTML. See my two Javascript sections now. Include both in the `<script>` section of your code after the `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery it's quite simple to do:

```
<form>
    <span id="city">New York</span>
    <a id="edit" href="#"> X </a>
</form>
```

And the script would be:

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
    $("#city").replaceWith('<input id="edit-city" type="text" name="city" />');
    $("#edit-city").focus();
    return false;
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/PRzDn/4/).